# Importing a CSV into SQL when there is a "," in the field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I need to import a CSV into a SQL 2008 database.  One of the fields is a directory, and apparently there are over 1600 rows that have a "," in the field name.  This field is now broken out incorrectly in my database.  There are over 100000 rows total.

How can I avoid this and modify my statement?

Here is the creation of the table:

```
create table tablename
(
Directory       varchar(1000),
Name            varchar(1000),
Size            varchar(50),
CreationTime    varchar(100),
LastAccessTime  varchar(100),
LastWriteTime   varchar(100)
)
```

Below is the code I used to import it:

```
BULK
INSERT tablename
FROM 'c:\EmailCSVs\myfile.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

An example in the directory field looks like this:

```
\\drive\share\nightly.175\savemail\user\(Monday, January 10, 2011, 500 PM)
```

And here is an example row in the CSV:

```
"\\drive\share\nightly.175\savemail\user\(Monday, January 10, 2011, 500 PM)","Archive #1.1.pst","271360","1/14/2011 8:37:05 AM","6/1/2011 12:00:38 AM","1/14/2011 2:45:27 PM"
```

Comment: What directory field? Show the create statement of your table please.

Comment: Added the version (2008) and the create statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `FIELDTERMINATOR='","'` a try.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to replace all the field separating commas in the csv file with the pipe char | then set

```
FIELDTERMINATOR = '|'
```

This is a standard technique used by many DBA's when the commas cant be escaped or removed

Answer (score 0):

You might try to bulk insert using a [format file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx).  This allows you to specify different terminators for each field, among other things.  For example, most fields might have the fieldterminator set to `,` whereas the offending comma-laden field might be `","`.

Another possibility is to open the csv in excel and create a [linked server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397) to that.